# The getter SearchableText was called before Null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am building an autosearch, as the user types the data gets populated from the widget class `TopSearchWidget` which has a animated Container but I keep getting the error `The getter 'searchableText' was called on null.`

The main class

```
class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  SearchScreen({
    this.controller,
     Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  TextEditingController dropOffTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  PickerMapController controller = PickerMapController(initMapWithUserPosition: true);

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    dropOffTextEditingController.addListener(textOnChanged);
  }

  void textOnChanged() {
    controller.setSearchableText(dropOffTextEditingController.text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, top: 30.0, right: 25.0, bottom: 20.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(width: 18.0),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: dropOffTextEditingController,
                            onTap: () {
                              dropOffTextEditingController.clear();
                              controller.setSearchableText("");
                              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                              //TopSearchWidget();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: TopSearchWidget(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The widget class

```
class TopSearchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TopSearchWidgetState();
}

class _TopSearchWidgetState extends State<TopSearchWidget> {
  PickerMapController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = SearchScreen.of(context);
    controller.searchableText.addListener(onSearchableTextChanged);
  }

  void onSearchableTextChanged() async {
   //do something
  }
}
```

There is an error called on Positioned(...)

```
The getter 'searchableText' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: searchableText
```

Comment: I think. your dropOffTextEditingController have null value or it is empty. Try using null safety, i.e. dropOffTextEditingController.text??" " and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes you are correct. This happens when I start the program for the first time. Where should I add this ?

Comment: Doesn't the error points to the line that is problematic? It might also be coming from the `SearchScreen.of(context);` in the initState function... Could you `print(controller == null)`?

Comment: I dont get any thing back, but I did what you told me to do and have updated the error in the post.

Comment: @pannam In the textOnChange() method, instead of dropOffTextEditingController.text, insert dropOffTextEditingController.text??" ".